# Combination C code for a random set of integers

Tags: c, algorithm, combinations

I have a random set S={3,12,15,24,33,40} and I need to generate subsets of size 3 from this set.Most of the examples and explanations regarding combination involved a set of increasing and ordered values like S1={1,2,3,4,...n}. Using the combination formula,I found that the number of possible combinations is 20 but can't figure out how to generate that list in C.

What if the set is random like S above and how do I get the possible list without duplicates in C?

Thanks.

Comment: Do you need to generate all combination or generate single combinations at random?

Comment: List of combinations - for this I am guessing 20 combinations that I will later sort.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the algorithms you have seen that have increasing, ordered values and simply replace those with the values in your list.

For example, the combinations (0-indexed) would be:

```
0, 1, 2
0, 1, 3
0, 1, 4
...
...
```

Then have an array with your numbers

```
int array[] = { ...values... };
```

and change the combinations to:

```
array[0], array[1], array[2]
array[0], array[1], array[3]
...
...
```

Answer (score 1):

You can generate all combinations of n items recursively. Something like this should work:

```
void combos(int[] values, int[] used, int[] selected, int len, int needed, int next) {
    int i;
    if (needed > 0) {
        /* select each available item as the next item and recurse */
        for (i = 0; i < len; i++) {
            if (!used[i]) {
                used[i] = 1;
                selected[next] = values[i];
                combos(values, used, selected, len, needed-1, next+1);
                used[i] = 0;
            }
        }
    } else {
        /* selected[0] .. selected[next-1] contains a combination */
        reportCombination(selected, next);
    }
}
```

Call this with `next=0` and `needed=3` to get the ball rolling and it should generate 20 calls to `reportCombination`, each with a unique combination of 3 values. (If you need to collect an array of all combinations, then you don't need `reportCombination`, but you will need extra bookkeeping arguments or else some global variables.)

Answer (score 0):

You are asking for a subset of the [Power set](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_set) of *S*, called by convention *P(S)* — namely all three-element sets in the Power set *P(S)*.

You could modify the Power set function in [this C code example](http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Power_set#C) to output sets of a certain cardinality (count).

Answer (score 0):

Use the **cartesian product** of the same set again by **removing the repeations**,,
try this code,,

```
int array[6]={3,12,15,24,33,40};
int combinations[20][3];
int n=0;
for(i=0;i<4;i++)
{                      //loops for 1st num in combination
   for(j=i+1;j<5;j++)
   {                       //loops for 2nd num in combination
     for(k=j+1;k<6;k++)
     {                         //loops for 3rd num in combination
        combinations[n++]={array[i],array[j],array[k]};
     }
   }
}
```

At-last the combinations 2D array will have all the possible combinations of numbers without repeatition